# JIttery rendering and ghost trail behind platformer character in Godot

Tags: godot, platformer, godot-4

I have no gamedev experience and I just started learning. I wanted to develop a basic [platformer](https://github.com/alturkovic/platformer) to learn.

I got stuck pretty soon with rendering in Godot. When I run the game, it just feels... Jittery... There is sort of a "ghost trail" behind my player, most noticeable when jumping. The run animation also does not seem very clear to me.

I am running it on: `Vulkan API 1.2.231 - Forward+ - Using Vulkan Device #0: Apple - Apple M1` using `Godot Engine v4.1.1.stable.official.bd6af8e0e`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/rendering/jitter_stutter.html#macos), I should be able to run this without seeing any stutter, and I did not expect jitter since my MacBook Pro 13 should run at 60Hz.

I have read several articles and forum posts online on this issue, and I think I am using `delta` in my processing correctly and that my `AnimationPlayer` is configured fine. I made sure that VSync is enabled, my stretch mode is set to `canvas_items`, my `Default texture filter` is set to `Nearest` and I have enabled both `Snap 2D transforms to pixel` and `Snap 2D vertices to pixel`.

My player movement logic is written in `_physics_process` method. I have also tried doing it in `_process`, but I don't notice any difference.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

-- EDIT --

I mispoke originally and wrote that I am experiencing stutter instead of jitter.

Comment: I have faced cases of jitter that I just cannot explain, but let us try... Given the settings you mention, I'm assuming this is a 2D pixel art game, is that correct? Can you show how this jitter and "ghost trail" looks like? Did you try the other VSync modes (mailbox and adaptive)? Can you tell if it is it just your player movement, or is it the the camera, or something else? Have you tried any kind of motion interpolations? What is the simpler code (perhaps set it up in a new project) that shows the problem?

Comment: I included the link to my source code in the question :) Maybe I should have been more clear about it now that I think about it... It is the platformer link in the first paragraph.

Comment: I see, I downloaded and ran it on Godot 4.1, but I do not see jitter nor a ghost trail on the game. I do not know if this related to hardware/OS※. Perhaps you are having an after image? I had the doubt on my end, so I recorded video and went frame by frame to confirm, and I didn't see any issue on the recorded video. ※ I'm running on: Godot v4.1.stable - Windows 10.0.19045 - Vulkan (Forward+) - dedicated NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (NVIDIA; 31.0.15.3742) - Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100 CPU @ 3.70GHz (4 Threads)

Comment: I guess it is due to the lack of a dedicated GPU. I assumed that I should be able to run a 2D demo like this one smoothly, but it just does not seem smooth at all to me. Thanks for confirming it. If you post it as an answer, I'll gladly accept this as an answer.

Comment: You have a rather simple scene, the kind I would not expect to have performance issues. So the way I see it, it might be a platform specific bug in Godot. That reminds me of something else you could try: the other renderers aside from Forward+. In a similar order of ideas: you could try making an equivalent scene on Godot 3... If it works: 1. you have a version of Godot you can use, and 2. we would know for sure it is something in Godot, something that changed between Godot 3 and 4.

Comment: I have tried all the VSync options and renderers, but I saw no improvement. I took a small recording to demonstrate my issue: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6i3yz1q69rdqyvt9kwwnu/Screen-Recording-2023-10-01-at-09.17.36.mov?rlkey=3hyfcd84hu19b43g5xog2rj4m&dl=0 The recording makes it look a little bit worse than it actually is. The movement is smooth, I wouldn't describe it as a performance issue, it is just that the rendering does not seem clean, it is kinda blurry.

Comment: I would have said the opposite: it is not blurry, each frame is clear (which is expected as Godot does not have a motion blur feature).

Comment: I understand your point. I feel like I am having problems explaining the issue, the movement itself "feels blurry" to me since it looks like there are multiple player sprites visible when jumping in the game, creating the "ghost trail". When running for an example, I cannot distinctively see the players eyes since it feels like there are overlapping sprites rendered slightly offset one from another. If I bump the speed, I can even see the ghost trail while running. The frames themselves are clear.

Comment: I do not see "ghost trails" on your video or running your code. Of course there is [Persistence of vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision), but I don't think that's it. What you say suggest to have the character move slower. In fact, you are reminding me of [What Is Video ??](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=buSaywCF6E8)  and [CD / Interlacing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eu_KjKsnpM)- So, I'm wondering if the solution is elsewhere. Are you watching on a TV? Does it have game mode/movie mode settings? It is doing frame/motion interpolation? Interlacing interpolation?

Comment: I am not using an external display. I have recently got a Macbook Pro 16 M2. I have tried capping its native 120Hz refresh rate to 60Hz, but that didn't help either. I have double checked with a couple of people and they see the "trail" on my screen also.

Comment: That leaves them trying your game in other computers/displays. I suppose there is a chance it is just me. Regardless I don't think I would have a solution one way or the other.

Comment: With the new Godot 4.2.dev6 ANGLE is available under the Compatibility renderer. Look in Project Settings -> General -> GL Compatibility. It should work around driver problems, and some people say it fixes stutter for them. You might want to try it.

Comment: I tried it and it did not help. I have exported my game to exe and sent it to one of my friends who confirmed that they do not see the trail they saw on my Macbook, so it is obiously only on my end, presumably due to the lack of a GPU.

Comment: Well, I'll write that as an answer. Edit: To moderators, feel free to move to chat or remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing (both on my end and OP end) with different rendering backends (including Godot support for ANGLE, on prerelease at the time of writing), and the common advice regarding jittering and stutter, we have found out that:

- The movement in Godot seems to be performant and smooth, yet the visuals are not desirable (what OP describes as a "ghost trail").
- It is possible to export the game, and other can play it without the issue.
- The issue is rooted in hardware, and it seems that it cannot be fixed via Godot configuration. It is unclear to me if this is purely a GPU issue, or if there are other issues elsewhere on the video stack (e.g. OS, driver, display).
- Thus, changing the hardware is only solution found at the time of writing.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I appreciate it!